# Error while submitting a spark scala job using spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I have written a simple app in scala using Eclipse -> New Scala Project.

I am using Scala 2.10.6 and Spark 2.0.2. The app is compiling without error and I also exported the jar file.

I am using the following command to execute the JAR

```
spark-submit  TowerTest.jar --class com.IFTL.EDI.LocateTower MobLocationData Output1
```

The scala code snippet is as follows

```
package com.IFTL.EDI

import scala.math.pow
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object LocateTower {
def main(args: Array[String]){

//create Spark context with Spark configuration
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("TowerCount"))

//helper to add locations function used as a helper in finding tower 
centroid
def addLocations(p1: (Double,Double), p2: (Double,Double)) ={
(p1._1 + p2._1,p1._2 + p2._2)
 }
}
```

This is not the full code. when I run this, I get the following error.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ spark-submit  --class com.IFTL.EDI.LocateTower 
 TowerTest.jar MobLocationData LocationOut1
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.IFTL.EDI.LocateTower
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:176)
 at 

org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$
runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:689)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I am new to spark and scala, so not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Is your class inside the package `com.IFTL.EDI`?

Comment: yes it is.. I forgot to mark that first line ( package com.IFTL.EDI) as code..

Answer (score 0):

Try with this order, if you want to pass some parameters you can put them after the jar file now, make sure you specify path to the jar or run it from jar location
spark-submit  --class com.IFTL.EDI.LocateTower /Users/myJarFilePath/TowerTest.jar

Try like that first, ones you have it working you can add command line arguments

Comment: I tried something like `spark-submit --class com.IFTL.EDI.LocateTower /home/cloudera/TowerTest.jar` but still getting the same error...

Comment: what is your build tool, create and uber jar file

Comment: I used eclipse(Oxygen Release (4.7.0) and installed Scala IDE 4.2.x for development and referenced spark jars from spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7. Then exported the jar which got created without any errors. I didn't use any other tool.. Do you have any reference links for the same if I need to do differently?